# What does the question mark character ('?') mean?

Tags: c

What does a question mark (`?`) in C mean?

Comment: Could you give us a contextual example of where you're seeing the '?'?

Comment: @bitcrazed: Just curious: what other use than the ternary operator are you thinking of?

Comment: @chris it's also (in seriously old code) part of a [trigraph](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt0y4awe.aspx), as Benoit beat me to answering.

Comment: @bitcrazed: I read about those, never seen them in actual code though. Not even in really old code ;)

Comment: @chris You're more likely to accidentally enter one and get compiler warnings about them rather than find real examples, yes.

Comment: @bitcrazed: Unless you enable them on purpose, most compilers I used disable them by default.

Comment: The question is too broad, there needs to be some context and a code example or it can't be answered. `?` could be a question mark as part of text, as part of a `\?` escape sequence, as part of the conditional operator `?:` (in which case the `:` is mandatory) or as part of a trigraph. All the answers guessing that it is the conditional operator are just that - guesses. The OP hasn't answered to the very valid request for clarification by Rich Turner in 2011, so I don't think this can be salvaged.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`?` is the first symbol of the `?:` conditional operator.

```
a = (b==0) ? 1 : 0;
```

`a` will have the value 1 if `b` is equal to `0`, and 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 13):

Additionally to other answers, `?` can be part of a [trigraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs).

Comment: It can also be part of a string or character in general without being a trigraph: `char c = '?'; char const * s = "?"`.

Answer (score 11):

This is a [ternary Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) which is conditional operator uses like **if-else**

example

```
int i=1;
int j=2;
int k;
k= i > j ? i : j;
//which is same as
if(i>j)
  k=i;
else
  k=j;
```

**Usage:**
Syntax of **?:** is

```
assignment_Variable = Condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false;
```

Answer (score 4):

That’s probably a part of the [ternary operator](http://www.google.com/search?q=c+ternary+operator):

```
const int numApples = …;
printf("I have %i apple%s.\n", numApples == 1 ? "" : "s");
```

Comment: Just to save future generations on any confusion here. It is the "conditional operator". It just happens to be a ternary operator, of which there is only one in C and C++. There are lots of unary (~, !, -) and binary (+, -, <<) operators in C/C++ as well. Neato!

Answer (score 3):

This is a so called conditional operator. You can shorten your if else statement with this operator.

The following link should explain everything

http://www.crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/The-question-mark-operator.html

Answer (score 2):

It is a conditional operator. For example refer the below link
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_operator

Answer (score 2):

Its the `ternary` operator, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation#C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_C.23.2C_Objective-C.2C_Java.2C_JavaScript.2C_ActionScript

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the '?' is the ternary operator. Its grammar is:

```
RESULT = (COND) ? (STATEMEN IF TRUE) : (STATEMENT IF FALSE)
```

It is a nice shorthand for the typical if-else statement:

```
if (COND) {
    RESULT = (STATEMENT IF TRUE);
} else {
    RESULT = (STATEMENT IF FALSE);
```

as it can usually fit on one line and can improve readability.

Some answers here refer to a trigraph, which is relevant to the C preprocessor. Take a look at this really dumb program, `trigraphs.c`:

```
# /* preprocessor will remove single hash symbols and this comment */
int main()
{
    char *t = "??=";
    char *p = "??/"";
    char *s = "??'";
    ??(, ??), ??! ??<, ??>, ??-
    return 0;
}
```

invoking only the c preprocessor by running `gcc -E -trigraphs trigraph.c` the output is

```
int main()
{
 char *t = "#"
 char *p = "\"";
 char *s = "^";
 [, ], | {, }, ~
 return 0;
}
```

Hopefully that clarifies a little bit what a trigraphs are, and what a '?' "means" in C.