# What does the '?' character do in this operation?

Tags: c#, operators

I'm just reading through some friends code and writing a test harness for it, and I've come across something that's bugging me:

```
Console.WriteLine(inputString + (isPalindrome(inputString) ? displayConditions(" some text 1", 
ConsoleColor.Black) : displayConditions("some text 2", ConsoleColor.White)));
```

What does the '?' symbol do in this operation?

A general description of what's being called would be greatly appreciated. I can't seem to find an answer online or in any of the books I have.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Thank-you I don't know how I couldn't find that on msdn Haha!

Comment: That's the [conditional operator `?:`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx). Often called "the ternary operator" since it's the only ternary operator (an operator having three arguments) C# supports.

Comment: Same question, only for C, not C#, but the answer is the same: [What does ? in C mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885143)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does ? in C mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885143/what-does-in-c-mean)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be the ternary operator.

`x ? y : z` should be read as

```
if ( x )
    y;
else
    z;
```

Comment: Technically, **a**, not **the**, ternary operator. This one is the *conditional* operator, otherwise known as the *?:* operator.

Comment: I agree that technically it is "a" and not "the" ternary operator.  That got me thinking but I am drawing a blank.  Which other ternary operators are there?

Comment: If there is none other, then, "the" should be correct.  Isn't it?

Comment: It's called the *conditional operator*. It is a ternary operator. There are no other ternary operators today. I'm being careful and correct with my language; I'm a software developer, and my compiler complains if I'm not so careful. The [reference documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4213hs1(v=vs.71).aspx) agrees with me, FWIW.

Comment: Agreed, but if it is the only operator of its kind, the question of "a" vs "the" becomes nitpicking.  I agree that I should have called it the conditional operator to begin with.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta The C# spec acknowledges both usages: "The ?: operator is called the conditional operator. It is at times also called the ternary operator." It is certainly common usage when speaking informally.

Comment: @mikez, without dragging this out *too* much longer, what I'm hearing is "ternary isn't *that* much worse a way to describe this than conditional". Conditional is the proper formal term, it produces better Google results, and it's what the Microsoft documentation that new developers read first actually uses. The top-voted answer to this question should include the correct term somewhere...

Answer (score 4):

It is called [Conditional Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ty67wk28%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

It is a concise way to write a condition where you need to assign a value based on the result of a comparison

Practically it means

```
result = (evaluate a condition) ? (expression to return if the condition is true) : 
                                  (expression to return if the condition is false)
```

Comment: Technically, it's the *conditional operator*, which happens to be a ternary operator.

Answer (score 1):

That's the [conditonal operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ty67wk28%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

It's also commonly known as the "ternary operator", but that only means an operator with three operands. That doesn't say anything about what the operator does, but it's the only operator in C# that has three operands.

Answer (score 0):

Ternary operator

[Mircosoft link to the ?: operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ty67wk28%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Pretty much an inline if statement

Answer (score 0):

It's the ternary operator. It's used to replace statements that involve `if {} else {}`.

So for example instead of doing something like:

```
bool value = false;
string myString;
if (value){
  myString = "something";
else{
  myString = "something else";
}
```

You can do:

```
string myString = (value) ? "something" : "something else";
```

The expression before the `:` will be evaluated if the condition before the `?` is true, otherwise, the expression after the `:` will be evaluated.

This can also be used for returns:

```
return (myCondition) ? "yes" : "no";
```