# return statement with conditions ? and :

Tags: c, return

I am very beginner in c and I am reading now the classic example of the TicTacToe game.
I am not sure about what this **return** statement does:

```
  {.....
     return (ch == X) ?O :X;
```

This must be some conditional statement on the variable ch (that in my case stands for the player (X or O) but I am not sure about its meaning. Can anyone please tell me what does it do?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#C

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does ? in C mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885143/what-does-in-c-mean)

Comment: Please have a look on [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).

Comment: thank you for all your answers and comments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means

```
if (ch == X) 
    return O;
else
    return X;
```

Answer (score 6):

This is called a ternary operator, because unlike many other operators, it doesn't take one or two operands, but three. A boolean condition and two values. In your example, if the boolean condition `(ch == X)` validates to true, O is the result of the operator. Otherwise, X is the result.

This can be rewritten as:

```
if (ch == X)
    return O;
else
    return X;
```

Answer (score 1):

If `ch` equals `X` return `O` else return `X`.

Answer (score 0):

The `... ? ... : ...` operator is called ternary operator. Its a shorthand for simple if statement. Lets see few examples,

**Odd/Even**

```
n % 2 ? printf ("Odd") : printf ("Even");

OR

printf ("%s\n", n % 2 ? "Odd" : "Even");
```

**Factorial**

```
int factorial(int n)
{
    return (n == 0 ? 1 : n * factorial (n - 1));
}
```