# What is the meaning of (condition ? ' ' : '\n') in a C program?

Tags: c

What's the meaning of:

```
printf("%.2f%c", arr[i][j], j+1<a-i ? ' ' : '\n');
```

More exactly the line:

```
? ' ' : '\n'
```

I can't understand. Maybe someone can explain and also compare the line

> ? ' ' : '\n'

in basic simple C program.

Comment: That is the ["conditional operator"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_operator). Basically the value of an expression with conditional operator is the value in the middle if the first value is *true*, otherwise the last value. Your 1st value is `j+1<a-i` which is either *true* or *false* depending on the values of `a` and `i`

Comment: Duplicate: [What does ? in C mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885143/what-does-in-c-mean)

Comment: `a ? b : c` evaluates to `b` if `a` is true, and `c` if `a` is false.  It's like an `if...else` that produces a value.

Answer (score 2):

It's the so-called ternary operator, which is in fact an if-then-else construction, meaning:

```
j+1<a-i ? ' ' : '\n'

IF j+1< a-i
THEN ' '
ELSE '\n'
```